# How to create multiple AE title in DCM4CHEE?

Tags: dcm4che

I want to create a mutliple receiving AE title which listening on same port but all AE titles are different

```
Example 192.168.0.1@localhost:11112  - send from A Location 
        192.168.0.1@localhost:11112  - send from B Location
```

Is there any other way to get different location in dcm4chee (pacs database).

Answer (score 1):

In the JMX Console, there is dcm4chee.archive, service=StoreScp. The called AE Titles field will accept multiple AE titles (backslash separator). This allows DCM4CHEE to listen on multiple titles (e.g. DCM4CHEE@localhost:11112 and MY_PACS@localhost:11112).